# Valores vacios al traerlos de una tabla jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Resulta que tengo esta función

```
function showData(){
var valores = [];
$(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function() {
  valores.push($(this).text());
});
alert(valores);
}
```

que se supone muestra todos los valores de una fila seleccionada en una tabla, pero solo me muestra el alert sin nada de valores

la estructura de mi tabla, la traigo desde una archivo php y queda así:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

sé que estoy haciendo algo mal al referenciar a la tabla y a los td, pero no sé que es, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

**SOLUCIONADO**

tengo esta funcion en la cual recibo el this que viene desde el onclick del boton y lo ocupo antes de .parents().

```
function showData(show){
var valores = [];
$(show).parents("tr").find("td").each(function() {
  valores.push($(this).text());
});
if(valores == null || valores == ""){
  alert("valores vacios");
}else{
alert(valores);
}
}
```

y este es el boton que viene desde php

```
"<td><button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='showData(this)'> Click    me</button></td>";
```

y esto fue lo que me funcionó. muchas gracias a todos los que comentaron.

Comment: Alexi, en donde llamas a la funcion showData()? Creo que es importante que lo pongas, porque con el codigo que muestras no sabemos a que esta haciendo referencia $(this).

Comment: lo siento, eso estaba mal creo yo, este es mi codigo en php de ese boton "<td><button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='showData()'> Click me</button></td>";

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar todo lo necesario.

Comment: o tengo que enviar el $(this) al hacer click en el boton? y si es así, como lo recibo en la funcion y como ocupo esa variable?

Comment: No tienes que enviarlo. Pregunta, necesitas ver todas las columnas, o solo la que presionaste?

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta :)

Comment: Alexi que bueno que lo solucionaste. Es mejor que publiques la forma en que lo solucionaste como una respuesta en vez de incluirlo en la pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: haré eso, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como llamas a la función en el evento `onclick` `this` contiene una referencia al objeto `window`, no al botón.

Puedes pasarle el botón como parámetro con `onclick="showData(this);"`:

```js
function showData(button){
  var valores = [];
  $(button).parents("tr").find("td").each(function() {
    valores.push($(this).text());
  });
  console.log(valores);
}
```

```css
th, td{
  font: Arial;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Col1</th>
   <th>Col2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Celda 1.2</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='showData(this);'> Click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Celda 2.2</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='showData(this)'> Click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Celda 3.2</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='showData(this)'> Click me</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

O, mejor, ya que utilizas jQuery, utilizarlo también para asociar los controladores de eventos:

```js
function showData(button){
  var valores = [];
  $(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function() {
    valores.push($(this).text());
  });
  console.log(valores);
}

$(function(){
  $('.btn').click(showData);
});
```

```css
th, td{
  font: Arial;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Col1</th>
   <th>Col2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Celda 1.2</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-primary'> Click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Celda 2.2</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-primary'> Click me</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Celda 3.2</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-primary'> Click me</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias, eso fue lo que había hecho. :)